# Label an array of numbers with names in r

Tags: arrays, r, char, numeric

I have a numeric array similar to this:

```
My.Array <- array(1:24, dim=c(3, 4, 2))
```

Which I would like to label with the labels

```
Labels <- c("Small", "Medium", "Large")
```

To do this in a column I'd usually use the following code:

```
My.Array <- cut(My.Array, c(0, 8 , 16, Inf), labels = Labels)
```

But this doesn't conserve the the dimensions of the array which I'd like to.

Could anyone help please?

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: Having a factor in an array is not typical. You could just do `My.Array[] <- Labels[cut(My.Array, c(0, 8 , 16, Inf))]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can assign the output of `cut` to the dimensions of the 'My.Array`

```
newarray <-  `dim<-`(cut(My.Array, c(0, 8 , 16, Inf), labels = Labels), dim(My.Array))
```